# CS:GO - How to disable the scoreboard opening?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Ok, so originally, my scoreboard wasn't showing up in-game when I pressed TAB. So, I opened the console and typed `+showscores`. The problem is, now, TAB doesn't hide the scoreboard and it opens up every time I respawn. I tried typing `hidescores` but that only works for one round.

Please help! I can't play with this.

Comment: Does `-showscores` work?

Comment: DId you just type +showscores or did you bind it to something ?

Comment: Try going into game settings and changing the binds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've just typed "+showscores" into the console and left it at that which is causing it to sporadically pop up. If you want to use tab to open and close it then you must bind the command to the key. To bind the command you simply need to type the following command into the console:

```
bind "TAB" "+showscores"
```

The following format will work for any command that you want to bind:

```
bind "key" "command"
```

Comment: No problem. If you want to see more examples of commands you can check out my autoexec configuration [here](https://gist.github.com/Mielzus/425676f8b795d19c9392e2a7d1a3b6a0)